# For discrete elliptic curves, can you find G, if you are given b and B?

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm

I know you cannot find $b$ if you are given $B$ and $G$, where $B = [b]G$,

but can you find $G$ given $b$ and $B$?

Comment: If you know the order of $G$, call it $q$, you can compute $b'=b^{-1}\bmod q$ and then $b'\cdot B$ should give you $G$ (if I'm doing my math right, else someone will correct me in another comment / answer, I'm too tired right now for a full answer / guaranteed info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G = [b^{-1} \bmod q]B$ where $q$ is the order of the group generated by $G$, assuming $\gcd(b, q) = 1$.

Comment: How do you find b^-1?

Comment: Use the extended Euclidean algorithm to compute the Bézout coefficients $s$ and $t$ so that $s b + t q = \gcd(b, q)$; then $s$ is your answer.  Or, use Fermat's little theorem and compute $b^{q - 2} \bmod q$.